# How to use different joomla template for a specific UserAgent String

Tags: templates, joomla, webview, joomla3.0

I have a Joomla plugin-driven portal. the plugin is installed and does what I need in browsers. Now I am trying to build a `WebView` App using the joomla-plugin html directly. I can do this by designing a new joomla template that looks like my app. Now if I activate the template, it will take over the web version.

How can I have a work around probably with a `UserAgent` string or anything else to specify the request is from the app so I can use the designed template instead of the default one, and the default one still works in other web browsers.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. How to make the webview identify itself

If you are in full control of the web view code, you can certainly send a predefined UserAgent string or even better a custom header (e.g. "X-App: my-webview").

If you just want to identify some devices by brand / screen / features, you may want to have a look at the [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) project.

## 2. How to switch template in Joomla

You have to write a System plugin that listens for the "onAfterInitalise" event, check for the custom UserAgent / header, and switch the template accordingly. The code will be more or less like this (untested):

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.environment.browser');

class plgSystemTemplateswitcher extends JPlugin
{
    private $webViewUserAgent = "myWebViewUserAgent";
    private $webViewTemplate = "myWebViewTemplate";

    public function onAfterInitialise()
    {
        if ($this->getUserAgent() == $this->webViewUserAgent) 
        {
            $this->setTemplate($this->webViewTemplate);
        }
    }

    private function getUserAgent()
    {
        $browser = JBrowser::getInstance();

        return $browser->getAgentString();
    }

    private function setTemplate($template)
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $app->setTemplate($template);
    }     
}
```